# How to draw a red shape on a black background in cv2?

Tags: python, opencv

I have an image with a black background. How am I supposed to draw a red shape on it? The red color should be (0,0,255) right? But it shows as black so it's not visible with a black background. The best I could do was to create a white rectangle in the following example. My question is how should I make it red? I think I'm missing something simple here. Please help.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = np.zeros((500,500,1), np.uint16)
cv2.rectangle(img, (200, 200), (300, 300), (0, 0, 255), 5)
cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.waitKey(100000)
```

You will see the rectangle doesn't even show up:

[image]

And the best I could do was a white rectangle like this:

```
img = np.zeros((500,500,1), np.uint16)
cv2.rectangle(img, (200, 200), (300, 300), (2**16, 0, 0), 5)
cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.waitKey(100000)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to draw color (3 channels) on a black (one channel) image. You need to convert the black image to 3 channels. Here is how I do it in Python/OpenCV

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# create one channel black image (grayscale)
img = np.zeros((500,500))

# convert to 3 channel black (color)
img = cv2.merge([img,img,img])

# draw on it in color
cv2.rectangle(img, (200, 200), (300, 300), (0, 0, 255), 5)
cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

The result is a red square outline on black background